# Is there a name for this distribution? $F(x)=e^{-e^{-x}}, f(x)=e^{-x-e^{-x}}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

It came out when limiting the distribution of $Y_n-\log{n}$, where $Y_n=\max\{{1 \leq i \leq n : X_i}\}$, $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are random variables obtained from $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the gumbel law. The wikipedia page about it : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution